# TeXworks Refuses to launch

Tags: texworks

please  I use miktex 2.9 in a windows 8. The problem is TeXwork which was functioning properly before, now refuses to launch, any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: make a bug report in the miktex issue tracker. Or use some other editor.

Comment: What happen if you use another editor, like [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/)?